# Contrib module remove

Tags: drush, 9, composer

I want to remove the content_sync module from my site. Firstly I uninstalled it with drush pm-uninstall, run a drush cex, drush cr and then removed it using composer remove. I removed also every custom class or service that was connected to it. Yet when I move from the main branch to this particular branch where I removed the module and restart the docker container, I get the following error:

```
 [warning] include_once(/opt/bitnami/drupal/web/modules/contrib/content_sync/content_sync.module): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory Extension.php:148
 [warning] include_once(): Failed opening '/opt/bitnami/drupal/web/modules/contrib/content_sync/content_sync.module' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php') Extension.php:148
Error: Class "Drupal\content_sync\Logger\ContentSyncLog" not found in /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 259 #0 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#1 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#2 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(273): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#3 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#4 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#5 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(249): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#6 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#7 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#8 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#9 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(449): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#10 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#11 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#12 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#13 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#14 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#15 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#16 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#17 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#18 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#19 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#20 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#21 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#22 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#23 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#24 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#25 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(273): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters()
#26 /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService()
#27 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php(284): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
#28 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php(250): Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->addDrupalModuleDrushCommands()
#29 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapManager.php(291): Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->bootstrapDrupalFull()
#30 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapManager.php(477): Drush\Boot\BootstrapManager->doBootstrap()
#31 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php(220): Drush\Boot\BootstrapManager->bootstrapMax()
#32 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php(186): Drush\Application->bootstrapAndFind()
#33 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(237): Drush\Application->find()
#34 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#35 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#36 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(51): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun()
#37 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(72): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run()
#38 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush(4): require('...')
#39 /opt/bitnami/drupal/vendor/bin/drush(117): include('...')
#40 {main}
Error: Class "Drupal\content_sync\Logger\ContentSyncLog" not found in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() (line 259 of /opt/bitnami/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: did you do all of this in one operation before it had a chance to uninstall the module in the environment? is it a memory based cache that needs clearing?

Comment: Does a container rebuild sort this out?

Comment: Errors like this generally be resolved through disabling the module on one deployment, and then removing the code on the next deployment. Either that, or making sure you run `drush pm-uninstall [MODULE]` before deploying the new code in which the module has been removed.

Comment: @Jaypan, fixed like this, thanks